# Unity - Inject different classes for the same interface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have one interface: `IFoo`
Two classes implementing that interface: `FooOne` and `FooTwo`
And two classes `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` receiving an `IFoo` parameter in the constructor.

How I configure unity so `ClassOne` receives a `FooOne` instance and `ClassTwo` receives a `FooTwo` using only one container?

I can't do it at runtime so it must be in the config file.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at the [Unity documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

For a more readable config file you should define type aliases for `IFoo`, `FooOne`, `FooTwo`, `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`. Then you need to register the mappings from `IFoo` to your implementations. You need to set a `name` for the mappings.
For the consumers of `IFoo` you need to register an `InjectionConstructor`.

Your config will look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection,
      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IFoo" type="UnityConfigFile.IFoo, UnityConfigFile" />
    <alias alias="FooOne" type="UnityConfigFile.FooOne, UnityConfigFile" />
    <alias alias="FooTwo" type="UnityConfigFile.FooTwo, UnityConfigFile" />
    <alias alias="ClassOne" type="UnityConfigFile.ClassOne, UnityConfigFile" />
    <alias alias="ClassTwo" type="UnityConfigFile.ClassTwo, UnityConfigFile" />
    <container>
      <register type="IFoo" name="1" mapTo="FooOne" />
      <register type="IFoo" name="2" mapTo="FooTwo" />
      <register type="ClassOne" mapTo="ClassOne">
        <constructor>
          <param name="foo">
            <dependency type="IFoo" name="1" />
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </register>
      <register type="ClassTwo" mapTo="ClassTwo">
        <constructor>
          <param name="foo">
            <dependency type="IFoo" name="2" />
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

That's the corresponding test that shows how it works.

```cs
UnityConfigurationSection config =
  (UnityConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration(config);
ClassTwo two = container.Resolve<ClassTwo>();
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(two.Foo, typeof(FooTwo));
```

---

**Update**

At runtime you can do it like this

```cs
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>("One");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooTwo>("Two");
container.RegisterType<ClassOne>(new InjectionConstructor(
  new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("One")));
container.RegisterType<ClassTwo>(new InjectionConstructor(
  new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Two")));
```

Comment: How would you do this at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

You need to give them registration names to do this:

```
// Create an instance of a service you want to use. Alternatively, this
// may have been created by another process and passed to your application
LoggingService myLoggingService = new LoggingService();

// Register the existing object instance with the container
container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>("Logging", myLoggingService);

// Register a mapping for another service your application will use
container.RegisterType<IMyService, myDataService>("DataService");

// When required, retrieve an instance of these services
IMyService theDataService = container.Resolve<IMyService>("DataService");
IMyService theLoggingService = container.Resolve<IMyService>("Logging");
```

Taken from [Resolving Instances Of Types Using Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

Comment: In my application, we have default implementation of the interface and that's registered using Unity. But consumers are free to have their own implementation and register it using `app.config`. Can you tell how to handle this case? How to ensure that non-default one is used if one such type is found registered ?

Comment: Check out the answer from @SebastianWeber for details on using config files to register your services.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But that answer is not useful to me. Because I want to ensure that the default instance registered with the Unity is "unregistered" and the one configured by the user is always provided.

Comment: I would put your registration in the config file - then if they want to change it, they'll edit it to change yours to the theirs. This would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I setup in my application like this

Installed Nuget Package Unity version 4.0.1

```
<package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

In my App.config

```
<configSections>
     <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
</configSections>

<unity>
    <container>
        <register type="MyApp.MainWindow, MyApp">
            <lifetime type="singleton" />
        </register>
        <register name="UnityResolver" type="MyApp.Core.Interface.IResolver, MyApp.Core.Interface" mapTo="Avelyn.Core.Container.UnityResolver, Avelyn.Core" />
        <register name="NinjectResolver" type="MyApp.Core.Interface.IResolver, MyApp.Core.Interface" mapTo="Avelyn.Core.Container.NinjectResolver, Avelyn.Core" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

In My App.xaml.cs

```
var _container = new UnityContainer();
_container.LoadConfiguration();

IResolver _unityResolver = _container.Resolve<IResolver>("UnityResolver");
IResolver _ninject  = _container.Resolve<IResolver>("NinjectResolver");
MainWindow _win = _container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
```